# Flattening array understanding code

Tags: javascript, arrays

In another question of mine someone posted a really cool solution on how to flatten an nth nested array into one array. Since I did not want to start a long chat, and I still don't really fully understand what this code does, I thought I'd ask.

So my impression is that first in this case our array has length 2, and then it becomes 1 in the while loop. We then check is `array[1]`, is an array. It is so we proceed. Now here is where I'm a bit confused. I believe we call the `flatten` function again so we can get into the nested arrays, but I'm still kind of hazy on the reasoning. We then take `array[1]` and slice it, here doesn't slicing just mean getting the whole `array[l]` anyways? since we go from 0th position to the end since `slice()` has no parameters.

```
function flatten(array) {
    var l = array.length, temp;
    while (l--) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[l])) {
            flatten(array[l]);
            temp = array[l].slice();
            temp.unshift(1);
            temp.unshift(l);
            [].splice.apply(array, temp);
        }
    }
}


var array = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]];

flatten(array);

console.log(array);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/curw7mdp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going to assume you understand the basics of recursion. I'll walk you through line by line.

```
var l = array.length, temp;
```

Declares l equal to the length of the array, and declares temp.

```
while (l--)
```

This decrements l *after* the iteration of the loop (as opposed to --l doing it before);

```
if (Array.isArray(array[l]))
```

This is checking if the 'l'th element in the array is another array. This is important because it means this element isn't flat.

```
flatten(array[l]);
```

This is where it gets fun, the function recursively calls itself so that it can now traverse the sub-array. And if the sub-array contains another array, it can keep going down deeper. I believe this is head recursion.

```
temp = array[l].slice();
```

Looks a little weird, but this allows us to extract the array into a new variable called temp.

```
temp.unshift(1);
temp.unshift(l);
[].splice.apply(array, temp);
```

This is also a very janky way of writing things, but basically it puts 1 and l as the first to elements in the temp array, and then it calls splice on array, with temp as the parameters. Only the first two elements of temp are passed as parameters (the two we put in just a second ago), so it uses basically removes the sub array, and replaces it with the flattened version.

Comment: No, the array length starts at 3, and each iteration of the loop decrements it. [].splice doesn't do anything on its own, you're going to have to read up on the apply method. It's very weird syntax, I'm not sure the best way to explain it.

Comment: My apologies. Yes, its a 2 element array. I've been misreading it.

Comment: Also related to the apply function. Splice is a method that works on arrays, and so [] is an empty array on which to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

References: [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

See comments for detailed explanation.

```
function flatten(array) {

    // put the length of the array in l
    // and create a temp variable with nothing in it
    var l = array.length, temp;

    // while(l--) will iterate through 
    // each item in the array backwards
    // this is just a little faster than doing
    // for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    while (l--) {

        // The current item in the while loop is array[l]
        // (that's an L, by the way, not a one)
        // so this is saying "if current item is an array...."
        if (Array.isArray(array[l])) {

            // we call the function again (recursion)
            // if this is an array. eventually, one of 
            // the inner items will be something other 
            // than an array and the recursion will stop
            flatten(array[l]);

            // when you call slice() with no parameters
            // all it does is create a copy of the entire array
            // and then we store it in temp
            temp = array[l].slice();

            // adds the number 1 to the begining of the array
            // after we unshift one more time below,
            // this will become the second parameter for the 
            // splice() call below, which is the number of 
            // items to delete
            temp.unshift(1);

            // adds the current index to the begining of the array
            // this will be the first argument passed to splice()
            // below, the first argument for splice is the 
            // index to start splicing.. 
            temp.unshift(l);

            // apply()'s first argument is context, in this case
            // passing "array" as the context means the action will 
            // be performed on the array variable, 
            // which is the original arrray..
            // apply()'s second argumetn is an array, each item 
            // of the array is passed in order to the function 
            // as arguments
            // So basically this is saying.. "remove the current 
            // index (which is an array) and replace it with each 
            // of the items that were in that array
            [].splice.apply(array, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remember, we're iterating backwards (l--) so on the first iteration l will =3

Comment: lol, my mistake, you're right, there are 2 items in the array, and we l-- before each iteration, so on the first iteration l will actually =1, as you originally stated.

Comment: when you use `while()`, the decrement happens before the loop, not after. it will be 1 on the first iteration.

Comment: when you do --i it will evaluate `i` *after* the decrement, which means the loop will never iterate over the zero'th index. https://jsfiddle.net/rhsp3jgm/.

Comment: if this answer helped please hit the checkmark, if you like it you can upvote too. hope i helped.